# If $d$ is a singular value of an operator $T$, then is $d^2$ a singular value of $T^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I'm trying to prove/disprove a homework problem that is the title question. I'm not looking for an explicit answer, just some direction.
So, I've been reading Axler's book *Linear Algebra Done Right* and from what I understand,

> every operator on $V$ has a diagonal matrix with respect
>   to some orthonormal bases of $V$, provided that we are permitted to
>   use two different bases rather than a single basis as customary when
>   working with operators.

So that if we let $( e_1, ..., e_n )$ and $( f_1, ..., f_n )$ be orthonormal bases of $V$ then the matrix of $T$, an operator on $V$, is

$$M(T,(e_1,...,e_n),(f_1,...,f_n))  =  \begin{bmatrix}
  d_{1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & d_{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & d_{n}
 \end{bmatrix}$$

So, my thinking is that the matrix of $T^2$  is just the matrix above composed with itself and so would be

$\begin{bmatrix}
  d^2_{1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & d^2_{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & d^2_{n}
 \end{bmatrix}$

Am I on the right track or am I missing something?

Comment: I've no idea what the answer is since the above seems to be a rather unique, specialized thing, but could you give the *exact* reference in Axler's book?

Comment: Do you mean the exact page number of where I took the quote? If so, it's on page 157. The chapter title is "Operators on Inner-Product spaces" (chapter 7).

Answer (score 2):

Think of singular values this way: $T$ will rotate the unit ball, then stretch it to a coordinate-aligned ellipsoid with semiaxes $d_1,\dots,d_n$, then rotate that ellipsoid.

Imagine doing that twice. Will the stretch factors be $d_1^2,\dots,d_n^2$? Probably not, because we have rotations between stretching maps, which will spoil everything.

Once this is realized, a counterexample comes naturally: let $T$ be something that deforms and then rotates.  For example: 
$$T=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ has $1$ as its singular value, but $T^2$ is the zero matrix.